# Finding the Formula for a damped function with respect to its drawback lenght and string lenght

Tags: functions

I have a general damped function equation. But I need to figure out a general formula for the the change in the function with respect to drawback length and length of the string. So far i have figured out that the amplitude of the function equals the drawback length. Therefore, the function i so far have is 
$$
                                y= L \cos{(bx-c)}e^{-kx}
$$

Where $L$ is the drawback length.

Comment: What is $x$ in the function?

Comment: The x is the time

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear earlier. Basically the assignment i am doing is recording a pendulum and using software to made data points from the video. The goal of the assignment was to determine a function for 5 sets of data. 3 of them had a change in draw length and the rest had a change in string length. So far i have determined that the draw length equals the amplitude of the function. However, i need to find a general function that determines the effect of the string length (pendulum) on the function.

Comment: How do you think, the length of the string will affect the motion ?

Comment: The period of the function will change. But i am not sure how

Comment: https://opentextbc.ca/physicstestbook2/chapter/the-simple-pendulum/

Comment: If this is the answer you are suggesting - T=2pi *sqrt{L/g} then i cant use it. Its because my teacher said i cant use it. As i mentioned earlier i cant use hooks law. This formula is hooks law.